# Python 3 variable in string.len function

Tags: python-3.x

Hi everyone so I am new to programming in python and I was trying to write a program to translate a word into pig latin.  I ran into this error when I entered my input

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "pig_latin_translator.py", line 14, in <module>
    new_word = word[1:len(new_word)] + first + pyg
```

NameError: name 'new_word' is not defined

Here is my code.  I am sure this is just a noob mistake but I don't see why new_word isn't defined.

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = input('Enter a word:')

turn the original word into lowercase
word = original.lower()

if len(original) > 1 and original.isalpha():

    # get the first letter of the word
    first = word[0]

    # put it all together
    new_word = word[1:len(new_word)] + first + pyg

    print(new_word)   

elif len(original) == 0:

    print(original + pyg )

else:
    print('Empty')
```

Comment: What do you expect `new_word` to be, when it is used in the line `new_word = word[1:len(new_word)] + first + pyg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got this error because you have mistype the following statement.

```
new_word = word[1:len(new_word)] + first + pyg
```

the correct statement is

```
new_word = word[1:len(word)] + first + pyg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
new_word = word[1:len(new_word)] + first + pyg
```

with

```
new_word = word[1:] + first + pyg
```

because you are trying to get the rest of the word.